# Calculating read average length in a Fastq file with bioawk/awk

Tags: fastq, awk, bioawk

I found [here](http://cagt.bu.edu/w/images/8/81/Avg_read_len_fastq.awk) this awk script:

```
BEGIN {
  headertype="";
  }
{
  if($0 ~ "^@") {
    countread++;
    headertype="@";
  }
  else if($0 ~ "^+") {
    headertype="+";
  }
  else if(headertype="@") { # This is a nuc sequence
    len=length($0);
    if (len>4) {
      readlength[len]++;
    }
  }
}
END {
  for (i in readlength){
    countstored+=readlength[i];
    lensum+=readlength[i]*i;
    print i, readlength[i];
  }
  print "reads read = "countread > "/dev/stderr";
  print "reads stored = "countstored > "/dev/stderr";
  print "read average length = "lensum/countstored > "/dev/stderr";
}
```

and I just wonder if it is possible to shorten it with bioawk?

Comment: It might be possible.  What problem do you have with having a long script? Why do you want a shorter script? Or do you want a faster script?

Comment: Did anyone get the correct script for finding out the average read length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can also be done with regular awk.

```
awk '{if(NR%4==2) {count++; bases += length} } END{print bases/count}' <fastq_file>
```

The `NR%4==2` count the second line out of every block of 4.  `length` is a built-in that defaults to the length of the line, same as `length($0)`.  In this case you can inject you custom printing to the `END{}` block but `countread` and `countstored` will always be the same since the averaging is done on the fly.

Comment: Note that, like OP’s code, this will only work on FASTQ files that don’t break the sequence and/or quality string across multiple lines.

Comment: That is correct.  However that practice is highly frowned upon so should not be an issue with most FASTQ files

Comment: I've yet to ever encounter a FASTQ file which has sequence or quality on multiple lines, I think for all intensive purposes assuming 4 lines per record should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

This script is wrong because a quality string may start with `@`. With bioawk, it can be simplified to:

```
bioawk -c fastx '{ readlength[length($seq)]++; countread++ } END{...}'
```

The `END{}` block is the same as your original version.

EDIT: forgot `-c fastx` is the original answer. Thank @MattBashton for pointing this out.

Comment: Using the exact same END{} code from the OP fails in this example with `bioawk: illegal field $(), name "seq"`